# Setting an attribute without value for a mootools element

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I have to re-create the following html element using Mootools

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple />
```

for which I have used the following code

```
new Element('input', {
    'type': 'file',
    'id': 'file',
    'name': 'file[]',
    'multiple':''
});
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WdEkQ/).

The issue is I cannot get the `multiple` attribute to be set in the element. How can I achieve setting an attribute without value (in this case, `multiple`) in a mootools element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`multiple` is a boolean attribute, so you can pass  `true` as the value:

```
$('test').adopt(new Element('input', {
    'type': 'file',
    'id': 'file',
    'name': 'file[]',
    'multiple': true
}));
```